# Determining whether $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2y^{\frac{4}{3}}}{x^4+y^2}&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0&(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$

How do I determine whether $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$? That is to say, is $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$$ equal to $0$?

Comment: Check if $f(x,y)$ is coming out to be same for $(x,y)\rightarrow(0^+, 0^+)$, $(x,y)\rightarrow(0^-, 0^-)$ and $(x,y)=(0, 0)$, which should be $0$.

Comment: That's actually not enough to imply that the limit exists.

Comment: One way is using parametric form $x^2=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$, then 
$$|\dfrac{x^2y^{\frac{4}{3}}}{x^4+y^2}|\leq r^\frac13\to0$$
as $r\to0$.

Answer (score 5):

$(x^2-|y|)^2 \ge 0$ gives $x^4+y^2 \ge 2 x^2 |y|$, so
${|x^2 y| \over x^4+y^2} \le {1 \over 2}$.

Hence ${|x^2 y^{4 \over 3}| \over x^4+y^2} \le {1 \over 2}|y|^{1 \over 3}$.

Comment: You could mention the Squeeze Theorem to finish the proof.

Comment: Excellent!!!!!!